# Trying to display a "please wait" message in WPF during a long-running operation

Tags: c#, wpf, visibility, inotifypropertychanged, textblock

I have a *`please wait`* `TextBlock` in my XAML whose `Visibility` property is bound to an `IsBusy` property on my ViewModel (which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`). A separate button launches a long-running (2-3 seconds) process, like this:

```
IsBusy = true;

try
{
    // Do some long-running process
}

finally
{
    IsBusy = false;
}
```

But the *`please wait`* message never appears. I'm assuming the operation is running on the UI thread and therefore not giving it a chance to refresh? It *does* work if I run the above code on a separate thread, but I don't want the user to do anything while the operation is running - I'm happy for the UI to `freeze`.

How can I display the *`please wait`*  message? Or would I be better running it on a background thread and (somehow) locking the UI for the duration? I'm using .Net 4 btw.

Comment: Why not run it in the Background thread, and bind the `IsEnabled` of your Form/Window/UserControl/etc to the `IsBusy` property? Then when it becomes busy, the entire window gets disabled to prevent the user from modifying it while not locking up your application?

Comment: @Rachel sometimes the simplest solutions are the best - thanks! Running into another problem now though, but that's one for another SO question...

Comment: Ok, I've expanded that comment into an answer for you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct, it's not updating because you're running the code on the same thread, so rendering doesn't continue until after your process has finished.

You said you aren't using a background thread because you don't want the user to do anything while the operation is running, but it's never a good idea to completely lock up your application like this.

A better solution would be to bind the `IsEnabled` of your Form/Window/UserControl/etc to the `IsBusy` property. Then when it becomes busy, the entire form gets disabled to prevent the user from modifying it, while not locking up your application.

Answer (score 1):

At first `Visibility` property is not `bool`, so if you want to bind `bool` variable to it you need to use `IValueConverter`,and second, yes you are right, while UI thread is busy with your long running operation it will not execute anything else including visibility change.

I would suggest to use `WPF Toolkit` `BusyIndicator` expect of putting your own panel, it have `IsBusy bool` property.

Also froozen UI is not user friendly, generally I use this snippet

```
IsBusy = true;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{ 
  // Do work. 
})
.ContinueWith(t=>IsBusy=false, 
                        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Also note to check errors in `ContinueWith` method, or you will get exception on `Task` dispose

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code on a separate thread, you can still access the UI through the [**Dispatcher.BeginInvoke Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx).

```
if (!YOURCONTROL.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
    YOURCONTROL.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new Action(delegate()
        {
            //do something with the control/form/...
        }));
}
else
{
    //update your control
}
```

Comment: This is what I was doing, but as originally stated I didn't want to run in a background thread. With hindsight it's probably better to lock the UI in a controlled way, rather than just let it freeze.